# I am getting a comile time error when installing the pcaPP package from CRAN, any ideas what this may be due to?

Tags: c++, r, compiler-errors

I run install.packages('mvoutliers', dependencies=TRUE) in R 2.15.0 and fail at package pcaPP. Any ideas?

```
* installing *source* package ‘pcaPP’ ...
** package ‘pcaPP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/include/R/ -DNDEBUG -DR_PACKAGE_FILE -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c L1Median_HoCr.cpp -o L1Median_HoCr.o
In file included from smat.h:28:0,
                 from L1Median.h:5,
                 from L1Median_HoCr.cpp:1:
smat.base.h: In instantiation of ‘void SVec<T>::Copy(const tc_this&) const [with T = double; SVec<T>::tc_this = SCVec<double>]’:
L1Median_HoCr.cpp:93:32:   required from here
smat.base.h:882:4: error: ‘EqualDims’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
smat.base.h:882:4: note: declarations in dependent base ‘CDimCont<1u>’ are not found by unqualified lookup
smat.base.h:882:4: note: use ‘this->EqualDims’ instead
make: *** [L1Median_HoCr.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘pcaPP’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/library/pcaPP’
ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package ‘compositions’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/library/compositions’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a genuine error in the file `smat.base.h`.

You could try to get in contact with the maintainers of `pcaPP`.

Comment: It builds okay on CRAN though... is that possible if there's a genuine error in `smat.base.h`?

Comment: I actually edited the source code in smat.base.h and was able to get it to build and install after that. It seems like they are using a non-static function in asserts in a separate template class. By removing these asserts I was able to build. I have emailed them about this.

Comment: @Joshua: I wondered about this too, but these things can happen with different compiler versions.

Comment: @Palace: What version (off g++ I presume?) did you use?  And kudos on the patch---that's the way the system should work :)

Comment: @Dirk I dont have my laptop on me but I presume the very latest as I have arch which is a rolling release distro.

Comment: Real, real cutting edge, ie could it be g++ 4.7.0 ?  CRAN typically uses what is in Debian testing and is currently at 4.6.0